# Distributed Testing not running successfully in JMeter with 2 machines

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, distributed-testing

I am able to connect Master Slave. There were 2 issues.

Issue 1: While running a test am not able to see the response from JMeter. Test passed without throwing any errors.

Issue 2. While running a test I got the below errors from the response:
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 78:

http://umEntitlements/umEntitlements%7CuserID/

I tried the following steps:
1. CSV files are kept in same location in both Master and Slave machine
2. After that i placed the scripts, CSV file, in Bin folder

Please let me know if you have faced similiar issues and able to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should fix is the URL. %7 is | (pipe char), which I don't think you want to use here.

Comment: Thanks. I am not able to see the Response from Jmeter. For Example I am doing a dry run for 10 users in Distributed testing mode by enabling the Results Tree mode. I am not able to see any response there. However I verified that it is hitting the server and records are updated in DB.